# Extracting minutes between two timestamps and assigning different weights

Tags: sql, join, timestamp, teradata, weighted

I'm breaking my head over how to achieve this in Teradata.

I have two tables, and I need to extract minutes from the Run table and assign hourly weights to them based on the Weights table.

**Table 1: Run**

```
Machine     Begin               End
A           1/1/2010 08:00 AM   1/1/2010 10:45 AM
B           1/2/2010 10:00 AM   1/2/2010 11:45 AM
```

**Table 2: Weights**

Weights are assigned for every hour (Record 1 says weight is 10 for every run min between 8am and 9am)

```
Hour                Weight  
1/1/2010 08:00 AM   10
1/1/2010 09:00 AM   15
1/1/2010 10:00 AM   16
1/1/2010 11:00 AM   20
1/1/2010 11:00 AM   20
1/1/2010 12:00 AM   25
```

**Needed Result:**

```
Mach    Hour                Weight  Mins    Total (Weight*Mins)
A       1/1/2010 08:00 AM   10      60      600
A       1/1/2010 09:00 AM   15      60      900
A       1/1/2010 10:00 AM   16      45      720
B       1/2/2010 10:00 AM   16      60      960
B       1/2/2010 11:00 AM   20      45      900
```

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here are the sample tables

```
CREATE TABLE RUNS(NAME VARCHAR(50),START_DT timestamp(0),END_dt timestamp(0));
INSERT INTO RUNS VALUES      ('A','2020-01-01 08:00:00','2020-01-01 10:15:00');
INSERT INTO RUNS VALUES      ('B','2020-01-02 10:00:00','2020-01-02 11:45:00');

CREATE TABLE WEIGHTS(HOUR_MS timestamp(0),WEIGHT INTEGER);
INSERT INTO  WEIGHTS('2020-01-01 08:00:00', 10); 
INSERT INTO  WEIGHTS('2020-01-01 09:00:00', 15);
INSERT INTO  WEIGHTS('2020-01-01 10:00:00', 16);
INSERT INTO  WEIGHTS('2020-01-01 11:00:00', 20);
INSERT INTO  WEIGHTS('2020-01-02 10:00:00', 20);
INSERT INTO  WEIGHTS('2020-01-02 11:00:00', 25);
```

Comment: How big are those tables? How many hours in Weights? Brute force would be a join based on OVERLAPS, but this will result in a *product join*, i.e. lots of CPU

Comment: Thanks for the response! There's about 8k records in Run and about 35k in Weights (every hour for 4 yrs). Some sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a brute force approach using a non-equi-join based on OVERLAPS:

```
select 
   machine
  ,weight 
   -- get the number of minutes within the hour
  ,cast((interval(period(begin, end) p_intersect period(hour, hour + interval '1' hour)) minute(4)) as int) as mins
  ,mins * weight
from run join weights 
on period(begin, end) overlaps period(hour, hour + interval '1' hour)
```

Explain will show a *Product Join*, which results in high CPU usage.
There's a smarter approach using EXPAND ON, but it's too late for me, maybe tomorrow :-)

Comment: Learnt something new today! Thanks @dnoeth.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach using EXPAND ON in a subquery, followed by equality join:

```
SELECT machine
  ,TheHour
  ,weight
  ,CAST((INTERVAL(pd P_INTERSECT xpd) MINUTE(4)) AS INTEGER) mins
  ,mins*weight
FROM (
  SELECT machine, PERIOD(begin, end) AS pd, xpd, BEGIN(xpd) AS begin_xpd 
  FROM run
  EXPAND ON pd AS xpd 
  BY ANCHOR PERIOD ANCHOR_HOUR
  ) x
JOIN weights
ON begin_xpd = TheHour;
```

Comment: As I said, a smarter approach using EXPAND ON :-)

Comment: Should be `BY ANCHOR PERIOD ANCHOR_HOUR` to catch partial hours for BEGIN not starting at 00

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the response. The code isn't picking up the right values for columns 2 and 3 (hour and weight).  I've edited my original post to include table creation, and here's your code I modified - 

SELECT NAME
  ,HOUR_MS
  ,weight
  ,CAST((INTERVAL(pd P_INTERSECT xpd) MINUTE(4)) AS INTEGER) mins
  ,mins*weight
FROM (
  SELECT NAME, PERIOD(START_DT, END_DT) AS pd, xpd, BEGIN(xpd) AS begin_xpd 
  FROM RUNS
  EXPAND ON pd AS xpd 
  BY ANCHOR PERIOD ANCHOR_HOUR
  ) x
JOIN WEIGHTS
ON begin_xpd = HOUR_MS
ORDER BY 1,2

Comment: You found an optimizer bug (at least in 16.20.31.01). When run standalone `begin_xpd`returns the correct value, but when nested it's the same value from the 1st row for all rows. You or @Fred should open an incident. As workaround remove `BEGIN(xpd) AS begin_xpd` and join using `ON begin(xpd) = HOUR_MS`